# What is the plural for “son altesse”?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, accord, société

In french we use “*son altesse*” and “*son altesse royale*” as a honor title to speak about a royal family. I was wondering what is the plural of that title? If I was to design two or three personns that way, would I say “*ses altesses*” or “*leurs altesses*”? **Who or what is the “*son*” refering to in “*son altesse*”**?

Comment: I think **leurs altesse** fits better, but it is hard to say since it is no more used nowadays... **son** must be referring to the title of the person you are speaking of... as **le titre d'altesse de XXX**, raccourcit en **son altesse XXX**. But I'm not historian, so I can't affirm it. Just a personnal opinion based on experience.

Comment: @Random thank you for your note. I am currently living in a kingdom, so I often hear 'son altesse' and heard some people using the plural a few times, but I am not sure what is the right way...thanks.

Comment: With regard to your second question, here’s a discussion of the «[nous royal](http://www.stansstuff.com/quel-est-le-royal-nous/)», which touches briefly on the extension of the concept to other pronouns (paragraph 4). It doesn’t address the “son” directly, but it could be that the alternatives:1) “mon/mes altesse/s would put too much “undeserved” importance on the speaker (& away from his majesty); & 2) “le/les altesse(s) would be treating him/her/them as if they were common, albeit definite, articles. Anyway I think the “votre/vos/son/leur/s royals” is related somehow to the “nous royal.”

Comment: @PapaPoule thank you: that's very interesting, I do think also that it is related to the "nous royal"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> "Leurs Altesses" avec les deux majuscules
>   Aussi bien en France qu'en Belgique.

Une simple recherche sur [Google livre](https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&hl=fr&q=%22leurs%20altesses%22) renvoie 74900 retours pour "Leurs altesses" et 500 pour "ses altesses".

Une autre référence, le site de L'Élysée, une lettre officielle de François Hollande adressée ["à Leurs Altesses Royales"](http://www.elysee.fr/communiques-de-presse/article/lettre-a-leurs-altesses-royales-le-duc-et-la-duchesse-de-cambridge-a-l-occasion-de-la-naissance-de-leur-enfant/) le Duc et la Duchesse de Cambridge .

À noter qu'on commence par le "duc" avant la "duchesse".

Par contre quand on s'adresse à eux directement, c'est "vos", par exemple:

"Je prie Vos Altesses Royales d'agréer l'expression bla, bla. "

Comment: merci, ta réponse est parfaite!